# httpd redirect to main apache test page

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, httpd, mod-proxy

I have a task to configure  site-config like:

1) * must be redirected to backend

2)  **/test** must show main apache page

I've tried some cases:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/sample
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8090/sample
    BalancerMember http://localhost:9080
</Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /test http://localhost:80
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:80
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
 ProxyRequests On 
 <Proxy *> 
    Order deny,allow 
    Allow from all 
  </Proxy> 
  <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/sample
                BalancerMember http://localhost:8090/sample
                BalancerMember http://localhost:9080 
   </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    ProxyPass /test http://localhost:80 
    ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:80 
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```

In both cases I cant reach apache test page , always redirects to balancer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical thing to do is to exclude the `/test` URL path from your reverse proxy  by using an exclamation mark <kbd>!</kbd> in a [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive.

Then the `/test` URL will be served directly from your VirtualHost entry and will show content relative to a `DocumentRoot`, or you can map the `/test` path to a specific location on your file system with an `Alias`.

```
VirtualHost *:*>
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/sample
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8090/sample
    BalancerMember http://localhost:9080
</Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Exclude /test from the reverse proxy
    ProxyPass !/test 

    # Map /test to the CentOS directory with the test index.html
    Alias /test  /usr/share/httpd/noindex

    # Alternatively create /var/www/html/test and set the following DocumentRoot
    # DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/


</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Tks
I've just found info about exceptions , so it was 1 step for resolve.